# Is there any way to serialize a Map with a BigDecimal key as a BigDecimal and not as string using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

While trying to serialize a Map<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> using Jackson with property ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, the key is serialized as a string while the value is serialized correctly as a BigDecimal. This is causing issues when I deserialized it since it is deserialized as Map<String, BigDecimal>.

I need to serialize the key as a BigDecimal and not as a String, is there any way to do so?
I am using Jackson-all-1.9.11.jar, but I also tried using jackson-2.12.4 jars but the same appears.

Is there any solution? Or can I create a custom Serializer that only override the Map Serializer to be used automatically by the ObjectMapper in the case of the BigDecimal key? If yes, how can this be done?

Below is a code example, with the returned result.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   try
   {
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
      Map<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> map = new HashMap<>();
      map.put(BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.ONE);
      map.put(BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal.TEN);
      String str = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
      System.out.println(str);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

The result is as below:

```
["java.util.HashMap",{"10":["java.math.BigDecimal",10],"1":["java.math.BigDecimal",1]}]
```

Comment: JSON keys are string-typed, afaik. That's JSON. Why don't you deserialize the value into a custom class that has `BigDecimal` as the data type for the key, instead of using a map?

Comment: @ernest_k above is a small example, but in my case, the data is dynamic and can be very complex, and of any type. Also, maybe a HashMap of HashMap with many levels, so I am using the same serialization functionality for all cases ('mapper.writeValueAsString').

Comment: Deserialisation should work properly even for `BigDecimal` keys. Try: `mapper.readValue(str, new TypeReference<Map<BigDecimal, BigDecimal>>() {})`

Comment: @MichałZiober I cannot do so, my data is dynamic and we can have a scenario that the Map of BigDecimal is not the first level of the object so cannot manually cast them one by one. For that, I am using  ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL to serialize/deserialize data whatever the data and the types are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a set of custom key serialisers and deserialiser for each class you want to use as a key in a `Map`. For example, for numbers it could look like this:

```
class KeyBigDecimalJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Number> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Number value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeFieldName(value + "_" + value.getClass().getName());
    }
}

class CustomKeyDeserializer extends KeyDeserializer {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public Object deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        if (key.contains("_")) {
            return deserializeKeyWithClass(key, ctxt);
        }
        return key;
    }

    private Object deserializeKeyWithClass(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String[] parts = key.split("_");
        try {
            Class<?> aClass = ctxt.findClass(parts[1]);
            return mapper.readValue(parts[0], aClass);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.KeyDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapKeysApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addKeySerializer(Number.class, new KeyBigDecimalJsonSerializer());
        module.addKeyDeserializer(Object.class, new CustomKeyDeserializer());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);

        Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.ONE);
        map.put(BigDecimal.TEN, BigDecimal.TEN);
        map.put(2.1D, 2.1D);
        map.put(100, 100);
        map.put("TEN", "ten");

        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
        System.out.println(json);
        mapper.readValue(json, Map.class).forEach((k, v) -> {
            System.out.println(k + " (" + k.getClass().getName() + ") : " + v + " (" + v.getClass().getName() + ")");
        });
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
["java.util.HashMap",{"100_java.lang.Integer":100,"10_java.math.BigDecimal":["java.math.BigDecimal",10],"TEN":"ten","2.1_java.lang.Double":2.1,"1_java.math.BigDecimal":["java.math.BigDecimal",1]}]
100 (java.lang.Integer) : 100 (java.lang.Integer)
10 (java.math.BigDecimal) : 10 (java.math.BigDecimal)
TEN (java.lang.String) : ten (java.lang.String)
2.1 (java.lang.Double) : 2.1 (java.lang.Double)
1 (java.math.BigDecimal) : 1 (java.math.BigDecimal)
```

Comment: In my case, I have a Class that contains a Map<BigDecimal, BigDecimal>, so when trying the above the object containing the map serialized correctly. But, when deserializing it didn't enter to my custom deserializer and throw an InvalidFormatException `Cannot deserialize Map key of type java.math.BigDecimal from String "10_java.math.BigDecimal": not a valid representation` while using `mapper.readValue(json, MyTestClass.class)`. So, is there any way to force using a custom deserializer for Map inside objects and not only Maps that are standalone?

Comment: @HusseinZaraket, try to register the same key deserialiser for `BigDecimal` class: `module.addKeyDeserializer(BigDecimal.class, new CustomKeyDeserializer());`. It could be the same instance as for `Object.class`